# SQl Server 2012 error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created a table manually and after that selected script table as new query and changed table name and executed the query. I am getting the error as

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 12 Line 12: Incorrect syntax near
>   '('.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.[KitCodeProperties](
[KitPropertiesId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[KitCodeName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[KitCodeDescription] [varchar](200) NULL,
[ShippingInstructions] [varchar](200) NULL,
[DepartmentId] [int] NULL,
[KitCodeActive] [bit] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_KitCodeProperties] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[KitPropertiesId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: Which one is line 12?

Comment: When you changed the name, did you also change the constraint name?

Comment: The script as posted here runs just fine

Comment: It works, so make sure you don't have other commands in the command window.

Comment: Did you have a portion of the code selected (i.e. not running the full script), or have additional scripts above or below the script you have posted? I've used your exact code on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/515e6) and it runs fine.

Comment: Nope I just changed the Table name

Comment: i selected the completed code and executed..there is no other script rather than that

Answer (score 0):

I took you code and pasted it into my 2012 developer edition.  Had no issues creating the table with and without SET commands.

Therefore, the syntax looks good.

Are you selecting on a section of the window?

Make sure you are not selection anything in the new query window and press F5 to execute the whole window as one batch.

If this works, you were highlighting only a section of the code.

A simplified version of the SSMS code.

```
-- Remove old existing table
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[KitCodeProperties]') > 0 
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[KitCodeProperties];

-- Create new table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KitCodeProperties]
(
    [KitPropertiesId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [KitCodeName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [KitCodeDescription] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [ShippingInstructions] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [DepartmentId] [int] NULL,
    [KitCodeActive] [bit] NULL,
);
```

The cut down version works fine in SQL Fiddler.

[image]

Comment: can you please post a screen shot of SSMS and the error.  Also, trying running the simplified version of the code.

Comment: I created a table manually by entering the columns and saved table name as KitCodeProperties instead of dbo.KitCodeProperties. So the table is created as Domain/username.KitcodeProperties. So I want change the table name to dbo.kitcodeproperties. for that I slected the Domain/username.kitcodeproperties using script table as a new query editor and changed the create table name and trying to execute  and I am getting the above mentioned error

Comment: There is no such thing as users being part of the table name.  That was before version 2005.  You always have [database name] . [schema name] . [table name].  While a user can own a schema, you will never see [nt domain/user name] in place of the schema name after 2005. I really wonder what is wrong!

Comment: Trying running the code from another account and/or tool.  For instance, sqlcmd to another server.  Maybe something is messed up with your session settings.  However, code looks fine.

Comment: WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]                I deleted the above script from the query and it was executed successfully